# How to test BizTalk-Orchestrations

Tags: unit-testing, biztalk, messagebox, orchestration, bizunit

As the title of this post says I want to test a BizTalk-Orchestration. In past I did something like that by using BizUnit. But I was only able to test the Input, let the BizTalk-solution run and test the output. BizUnit helped me by automatizing this process.

So the question is:
How can I test every step in an Orchestration (for example the output of Transform component). How can I read the messages in the MessageBox while I'm testing that?
Does anyone know a great tutorial?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Johns-305 and would suggest that its not probably required to test every step of the Orchestration.
Still if you want to, you could put temporary Send shapes after every transformation and send them out to a FILE location so that you can understand what messages are being generated.
Also, you can make use of Orchestration Debugger if you want to understand the flow of the Orchestration.
You wont be able to see any messages that are created within the orchestration but are to published to the message box.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the orchestration in the BizTalk administrator console.

Just stop your orchestration. then in the BizTalk group you can attach debugger.

Then you can resume in debug mode

Comment: Can you clarify your answer?  Do you mean the Orchestration Debugger in the BizTalk Admin console, or did you mean to attach Visual Studio the the Host Instance process and debug there?  Both are possible.  And that is Dev testing, rather than automated Unit Testing that the OP is talking about.

Answer (score -1):

The first question you need to ask yourself is: *Do I really need to do this?*  Hint, the answer is no.

The Unit Test fad has long past and was never a useful thing with BizTalk apps.

Instead, focus on developing, with the business owners, a set of test cases that validate the entire app.  You then use these to test everything, not just Orchestrations.

During DEV, 97% of the time, testing in Visual Studio is all you need for Maps.